# Is this the right way to expose VLANs through VPN (VPN server location)?

Tags: vlan, vpn, architecture

Starting from the following network topology:

```
Internet --- ISP Cable Router --- Firewall --- Router --- rest of the network / multiple VLANs
             (port forwarding)       |
                                    DMZ
```

I had to expose two VLANs over the internet through VPN for two groups of users. To achieve this, I chose the following approach:

```
                                         trunk
                                      for exposed
                                       _ VLANs _
                                      /         \
Internet --- ISP Cable Router --- Firewall --- Router --- rest of the network / multiple VLANs
             (port forwarding)  (VPN server)
                                     |
                                    DMZ
```

The "rationale" of this choice was that as both the firewall and the router have the power to run the VPN server, running it on the Firewall will help share the load at the cost of an additional trunk port and cable. It also helps me split the responsibilities (external access rules and traffic shaping on the firewall, inter-VLAN rules on the router) and avoid having to expose any service on the LAN.

Everything's working as expected, however as I'm not a professional nor experienced (I'm learning), I'm wondering if it is the recommended approach (from a ease of management, traffic shaping, security perspectives).

For instance I could have done this as well:

```
Internet --- ISP Cable Router --- Firewall --- Router --- rest of the network / multiple VLANs
             (port forwarding)       |      (VPN server)
                                    DMZ
```

The questions I ask to experienced people are:

1. what are the risks of my choice if there are any?
2. what is the recommended way of achieving what I want to do?
3. could you please explain "why" so I can learn?

Comment: Removed mention of off-topic device models and primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

> what are the risks of my choice if there are any?

Given that the firewall is between your LAN, DMZ and the Internet there's no obvious risk. Everything depends on your firewall ruleset, of course.

> what is the recommended way of achieving what I want to do?

I'd do it the same way. Although I don't see the real need for a plain link and a VLAN trunk between router & firewall - a VLAN trunk should be able to handle everything. (I'm guessing "router" is an L3 switch that handles both L2 and L3 connectivity, otherwise the VLAN trunk wouldn't make sense.)

Alternatively, you could use a single, routed link between router and firewall - you could trust IP addresses/subnet association as it's a dedicated link.

But I don't think there's a "recommended way".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The "router" is a rb5009 mikrotik router whoes port1 is the WAN port with NAT, and port2 is trunk port carrying traffic tagged with the two vlans. Is it a bad idea ?

Comment: Your diagram indicates three ports, hence the comment. Separate WAN and (VLAN trunk) LAN ports are what I meant.

Comment: In the second method (router as vpn server), the firewall is completely bypassed. So you are trusting whoever/whatever connects to the VPN.

Comment: @Zac67 sorry if it was not clear: the "rest of the network" consists of switches, servers, printers, workstations.

Comment: @Ricky this is why I avoided this approach.